# Storing a handle to an object in string - C#

Tags: c#, string, object, save, persistence

I play a tile based game where there is a programmable C# emulator in-game.

Now, through a function in the emulator, you can get tiles as objects in scripts you create, but only if they are connected to the same grid(building) as the emulator block. I'm trying to store the object I get from the function in-game, so I can access it(get a handle) when I seperate it from the grid(Normally, when I seperate it, the emulator no longer returns me that object).

Also, the emulator can only store strings. So, I can't store it using file streams I think.

Is there any way to store an object or object reference in a string in C# so I can access it the next time I run the program ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serialize the object to JSON, save as a text file, and later read the text file and deserialize back into an object. You could also do with with a Binary serializer which will be even quicker, but not user readable and less forgiving.

Comment: Update: I tried it but it seems that the in-game scripting doesn't allow any serialization method I could find on the net. But I coincidentally found another quirk to achieve what I wanted without serialization, so thanks anyway for your answer, Accepting it because it can help someone else.